# Array based stack memory efficiency

Tags: vector, stack

I know that a stack can be implemented by dynamic array (e.g. std::vector in c++) or linked list.

When the stack is implemented based on dynamic array, the capacity will grow automatically the new item is push into the stack. **I'm wondering that when pop out items from stack, will the capacity of the array decrease?**

In some applications (e.g path search algorithms), many items will be pushed into the stack first and then pop out. The program ends when the stack is empty. If the capacity of the array didn't decrease, I will have a large empty array when my program ends.

Comment: That depends on the implementation

Answer (score 0):

[std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) uses [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) as container. It's resized as required, both up and down.